# Tapestry 5, jQuery UI Dialog and close action

Tags: java, jquery, tapestry

Using [tapestry5-jquery](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/) and [Dialog](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsjquerydialog) component, ¿How do I implement a close action for the parent dialog?. I mean a button that executes some code and then close parent dialog without changing of page.

This is the javascript only version of what I'm doing:

```
<div id="container">
  ¿Are you sure to delete selected items?
</div>

$('#container').dialog({
  modal : true,
  buttons:[{
     text: "Yes",
     click: function() {
        //Perform action here, then close dialog.
        $(this).dialog("close");
     }
    },{
     text: "No",
     click: function() {
        //Only close dialog
        $(this).dialog("close");
     }
    }
  }]
});
```

But I need to use Tapestry 5 tags and java class methods:

```
<t:jquery.dialog t:clientId="delDialog">
  ¿Are you sure to delete selected items?
  <input t:type="submit" t:id="delYes" value="Yes"/>
  <input t:type="submit" t:id="delNo" value="No"/>
</t:jquery.dialog>
```

Java class:

```
public class UserAdmin { 
  @OnEvent(component = "delYes", value = EventConstants.SELECTED)
  void delYesClicked(){
     //Delete selected items
  }

  @OnEvent(component = "delNo", value = EventConstants.SELECTED)
  void delNoClicked(){
     //Close dialog
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested mixin:

```
public class DialogButtonHandler {
  @Parameter(value = "dlgId", defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
  private String dlgId;

  @Inject
  private JavaScriptSupport javaScriptSupport;

  @InjectContainer
  private ClientElement element;

  @AfterRender
  public void afterRender() {
    javaScriptSupport.addScript(
      "$('#%s').click(function(){$('#%s').dialog('close');});",
          element.getClientId(), dlgId);
  }}
```

Markup:

```
<t:jquery.dialog t:clientId="delDialog">
    ¿Are you sure to delete selected items?
    <input t:type="submit" t:id="delYes" value="Yes" />
    <input t:type="submit" t:id="delNo" value="No" t:mixins="dialogButtonHandler" t:dlgId="delDialog"/>
</t:jquery.dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if the clientId is always the same (i.e. 'delDialog')

```
@Inject
private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;

protected void addCloseDialogCommand() {

    ajaxResponseRenderer.addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback() {

        @Override
        public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport) {

            javascriptSupport.addScript("$('#delDialog').dialog('close');");
        }
    });
}
```

...and call the method in your event handler:

```
@OnEvent(component = "delNo", value = EventConstants.SELECTED)
void delNoClicked() {
    addCloseDialogCommand();
}
```

This behavior could be implemented using a mixin that you apply on any element you want.

Comment: Tried the supplied code, didn't work. Mixin suggestion worked instead. I'll put it later.